# ¿Diseñar un patron repositorio para manejar múltiples accesos a datos?

Tags: c#, xml, lista

Me gustaría diseñar un patron repositorio para diferente formas de acceder a datos, que pueden ser:

- Archivos de Texto (llámense cvs, txt, etc)
- Archivos XML
- Acceso a datos Relacionales(mysql, oracle, mssql, postgres, etc)
- Acceso a datos Nosql
- otros (excel, word, pdf)

  para esto estaría bien crear una interfaz base como esta

  ```
  public interface IRepository<T>
   {
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(object parentId);
    T GetByKey(object keyValue);

    void Insert(T entidade, bool autoPersist = true);
    void Update(T entidade, bool autoPersist = true);
    void Delete(T entidade, bool autoPersist = true);

   void Save();
  }
  ```

...Y que la implementación de esta interfaz
se haga para XML:

```
public abstract class XmlRepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
 {//.....codigo implementación}
```

para cvs o archivos texto
    public abstract class TxtRepositoryBase : IRepository
     {//.....codigo implementación}

para datos desde SQL:

```
public class FacturaRepository : BaseRepository<Factura>, IFacturaRepository
{

    public IEnumerable<Factura> ConsultaFactura()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetCliente(int? id)
    {//**** demas codigo}
```

para el xml me base de el siguiente código [repositorio Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819680/xml-repository-implementation)

me faltaría como realizar un repositorio para acceso de datos nosql texto y para otros tipos de archivo.

**Si alguien a trabajado en algún momento esto?**  esta bien crear un repositorio base o crear interfaz de repositorio independiente para cada situación?

Comment: solo podras crear un repositorio base si hay algo en comun, por ejempo si usas entity framework el repo base podria ser el mismo para varias DBs, pero si el target es muy diferente no aplica

Comment: Yo hice uno y se usó la misma interfaz para cualquier tipo de archivo, la extensión era la que le ayudaba a la lógica a decidir a dónde enviarlo o qué hacer con él, saludos.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini tienen algun codigo de ejemplo?? en la implementación de la interfaz para archivos texto y otros?

Comment: @shop350 tiene algo de código que puedas compartir tanto para texto y digamos para ADO sin utilizar ningun ORM???